# c++ QSerialPort reading exceeding characters

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm developing a Qt Program to acquire data from an Arduino MEGA and I'm constantly facing the receiving of eventual unwanted new line characters, which totally messes up with parsing and validation schemes.

```
//Setting up QSerialPort

void MainWindow::on_abrirPorta_clicked()
{
serial_port->setPortName(ui->nomePorta->text());
if(serial_port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    if(serial_port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200, QSerialPort::AllDirections)
            && serial_port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity)
            && serial_port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8)
            && serial_port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop)
            && serial_port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl))
    {
        ui->lerPorta->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        serial_port->close();
        ui->saida->append("Failed to open USB port");
    }
}
}

//Reading data

void MainWindow::readData()
{
serial_port->write("a");
if(serial_port->waitForReadyRead(500))
    if(serial_port->canReadLine())
    {
        QByteArray dados = serial_port->readAll();
        ui->saida->append(QString(dados));
    }
}
```

Concerning Arduino, the following is executed every second.

```
       Serial.print("MV: ");
       Serial.println(MV);
       Serial.print("PV: ");
       Serial.println(PV);
       Serial.print("SV: ");
       Serial.println(SV);
```

Within Arduino terminal, it all works fine, but under Qt, the following happens:

```
 MV: 26.51
 PV: 24.
 91
 SV: 30.00

 MV: 27.04
 PV: 24.91
 SV: 30.00

 MV: 27.57
 PV: 24.9
 0
 SV: 30.00

 MV: 28.11
 PV: 24.89
 SV: 30.00

 MV: 29.18
 PV: 24.88


 SV: 30.00

 MV: 29.72
 PV: 24.87
 SV: 30.00

 MV: 31.86
 PV: 24.85

 SV: 30.00

 MV: 32.40
 PV: 24.84
 SV: 30.0
 0
```

Basically, a bunch of newline characters are being inserted in various points of the each piece of data. Anybody there got any idea about what might be happening here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a question: dies `append` automatically add a new line? Because the reason can be that you receive the "line packet" divided into two "bursts". Moreover why are you waiting for a complete line (`canReadLine`) but then read all the data (`readExisting`)? I'd use the `readLine` function... You can try to add dummy chars (e.g. `ui->saida->append("@" + QString(dados) + "#");`) to detect the beginning and the end of the transmission, so that you can better understand what is happening... I bet it's the `readExisting` ;) Change it with a `readLine` and it should work...

Comment: What is the type of `ui->saida`?  Also, you are using `canReadLine` to indicate if a line (or more) of data is available, but you read all available data after checking for a line of data.  You might want to use `readLine` instead of `readAll` to get only the next line of data.